# Why is Kafka Streams in Node sending me duplicate payloads after I terminate the process and run once more?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, stream, microservices

I'm pretty new to the whole micro service architecture so I've been using Kafka to retrieve and send data to and from micro services. I know how to send and retrieve data pretty well through regular consumers and producers (although I'm not an expert on it), but I recently learned about Kafka Streams and wanted to use it to streamline the data I'm consuming. I was able to collect the data from another micro service, but I noticed that if I terminate the process and run it again, I get the data back, PLUS another copy of the same data right under it. And if I were to terminate the process and run it again once more, I would have another piece of duplicate data right under the last duplicate! I would be able to collect the data even if I stopped running the other micro service providing the data, so I'm assuming the data is getting saved somewhere. Here is how it would look If i terminated it once and ran again...

```
TOPIC: requestAllUserData
[kafka-producer -> requestAllUserData]: broker update success
[
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    city: 'Northridge',
    age: 25,
    gender: 'Male',
    profession: 'Teacher',
    email: 'johntho213@gmail.com',
    username: 'JohnTho213',
    created_at: '06-05-2019',
    deleted_at: '09-29-2020'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: 'Mike',
    last_name: 'Brown',
    city: 'Topanga',
    age: 19,
    gender: 'Male',
    profession: 'Senator',
    email: 'mikebrown@gmail.com',
    username: 'MBrownYe',
    created_at: '07-04-18',
    deleted_at: null
  }
]
[
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    city: 'Northridge',
    age: 25,
    gender: 'Male',
    profession: 'Teacher',
    email: 'johntho213@gmail.com',
    username: 'JohnTho213',
    created_at: '06-05-2019',
    deleted_at: '09-29-2020'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: 'Mike',
    last_name: 'Brown',
    city: 'Topanga',
    age: 19,
    gender: 'Male',
    profession: 'Senator',
    email: 'mikebrown@gmail.com',
    username: 'MBrownYe',
    created_at: '07-04-18',
    deleted_at: null
  }
]
```

As you can see, I got the payload sent to me twice, and I only want to see it once. Does anyone know the possible reasons for this unexpected behavior? I followed the documentation here -> https://nodefluent.github.io/kafka-streams/docs/

I've included my code which differs very little from the code in the documentation below

```
"use strict";
const { KafkaStreams } = require("kafka-streams");
const { nativeConfig: config } = require("./KSConfig.js");
const kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(config);
const stream = kafkaStreams.getKStream();

stream
  .from("AllUserDataResponse")
  .forEach(message => console.log(JSON.parse(message.value)));

function streamTest(){
  stream.start().then(() => {
      console.log("stream started, as kafka consumer is ready.");
  }, error => {
      console.log("streamed failed to start: " + error);
  });
}

exports.streamTest = streamTest;
```

I am running this in my Server.js file, although I don't believe that information really helps. Also I've been trying to collect the data and store it in a list or array but havent had any luck doing so, so if anyone can help me do that as well, it would be greatly appreciated. Oh and  here is my KSConfig file, if it helps.

```
"use strict";


const batchOptions = {
    batchSize: 5,
    commitEveryNBatch: 1,
    concurrency: 1,
    commitSync: false,
    noBatchCommits: false
};

const nativeConfig = {
    noptions: {
        "metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092", //native client requires broker hosts to connect to
        "group.id": "kafka-streams-test-native",
        "client.id": "kafka-streams-test-name-native",
        "event_cb": true,
        "compression.codec": "snappy",
        "api.version.request": true,

        "socket.keepalive.enable": true,
        "socket.blocking.max.ms": 100,

        "enable.auto.commit": false,
        "auto.commit.interval.ms": 100,

        "heartbeat.interval.ms": 250,
        "retry.backoff.ms": 250,

        "fetch.min.bytes": 100,
        "fetch.message.max.bytes": 2 * 1024 * 1024,
        "queued.min.messages": 100,

        "fetch.error.backoff.ms": 100,
        "queued.max.messages.kbytes": 50,

        "fetch.wait.max.ms": 1000,
        "queue.buffering.max.ms": 1000,

        "batch.num.messages": 10000
    },
    tconf: {
        "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
        "request.required.acks": 1
    },
    batchOptions
};

module.exports = {
    nativeConfig
};
```

I'll be replying to any further questions any of you have for me. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you need to know that Kafka does not guarantee exactly once delivery (*we do have idempotent producers and transactions but I will pretend that they don't exist for the sake of simplicity in this discussion*). There could be quite a few scenarios leading to duplicates.

In your use case, say a message batch(m1-m5) is read by the consumer. It is processed (and printed as part of your logs) but before it gets committed to the broker, the process was terminated. In such case when the process is brought up again, it re reads the same message(m1-m5) because it was never committed to the broker.

That being said, duplicates can also come from producer. Say the kafka producer sends a message and the broker receives it but the ack from broker is missed due to some network failure. In such case producer may re-send the message resulting into duplicates. So in conclusion, you should expect duplicates in your kafka pipeline and hence try to make it idempotent.